# Über die Konstruktion "gehören + Partizip II"

Tags: phrase

Soweit ich weiß, bedeutet die Konstruktion "gehören + Partizip II" soviel wie "etw. muss (Partizip II) werden.

> Der Zoo gehört abgeschafft
>   Was gehört in den Schulranzen?

usw.
Vor kurzem bin ich jedoch auf den folgenden Satz gestoßen

> Dieser Grieche gehört zitiert.

Was nach meinem Sprachempfinden etwas aus dem Rahmen fällt. **Kann dieses Muster immer verwendet werden oder ist es nur auf einige wenige Verben beschränkt?**
Also kann man beispielsweise Folgendes sagen?

> *Die Regel gehört befolgt, der Tisch gehört aufgeräumt, das Baby gehört gefüttert usw.*

Comment: Der Füller gehört in die Federmappe, die mir gehört. Letztere gehört mal wieder aufgeräumt, denn sonst darf ich mir gehörig etwas über Ordnunghalten anhören

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja, man kann auch sagen:

> Die Regel gehört befolgt (sollte befolgt werden).
>   Der Tisch gehört aufgeräumt (sollte aufgeräumt werden).
>  
>   Das Baby gehört gefüttert (sollte gefüttert werden).

Immer mit der ungefähren Bedeutung: "sollte ... werden", also

> Der Zoo sollte abgeschafft werden.
>   Der Grieche sollte zitiert werden.

"Gehören" kann allerdings auch noch etwas andere Bedeutungen haben, wie in dem Satz mit dem Schulranzen. Da bedeutet es sowas wie "passend sein", "zutreffend sein" oder "zugehörig sein".

Answer (score 1):

Du irrst, wenn Du (wie im Titel) "gehören" nur mit dem Partizip Perfekt Passiv konstruiert sehen willst. Tatsächlich kann es auch mit anderen Partizipien stehen, je nachdem, ob eine Passiv- oder Aktivkonstruktion notwendig ist. "gehört zitiert" ist eine letztere solche, das gehört gewußt. ;-)